# SQL Query - Value can't be the same as preceding row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return some data based on the item number and transaction type. I only want to see the latest dates for each transaction type. How can I make it so that the transaction type in rn 1 for a given item number doesn't equal the transaction type in rn 2 for a given item number.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         [ItemN], 
         [TransacDate], 
         [TransacType],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ItemN] ORDER BY [ItemN] ASC) rn
     FROM 
         [Huxley].[dbo].[FGInvDetail]
     WHERE
         ([TransacType] = 1 OR [TransacType] = 3)) a
WHERE 
    rn = 1 OR rn = 2
```

Results from query

[image]

Comment: Sample data will help and which database?

Comment: Your textual description does not match with the logic of the query.  At this point, you should add sample input data, along with the current and expected output.

Comment: If you want the last date why you care for #2? In your image shouw both have same TransacType so how that should change your result?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to show the latest dates for each transaction type. So, the latest date for transactype = 1 and latest date for transactype = 3 for each itemN

Comment: *latest dates for each transaction type*: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ItemN], TransacType ORDER BY [TransacDate] DESC)` and then filter for `where rn=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding transactype to the partition and ordering by transacdate DESC. Finally you'll only want to keep rn = 1

```
   SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT  [ItemN], 
                        [TransacDate], 
                        [TransacType],
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ItemN], [transactype] ORDER BY [transacdate] Desc) rn
                    FROM [Huxley].[dbo].[FGInvDetail]
                    where ([TransacType] = 1 or [TransacType] = 3)
              ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```